# What Can be instantiation from a Metaclass

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

What can a class instantiation from metaclass? As I understand it, usually methods like`__init__`, `__del__`,`__call__` come from the default metaclass `type`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should not talk about inheritance but instantiation. Class is related to its metaclass in the same way how instance is related to its base class. Class is an instance of metaclass.

In particular every field defined on a metaclass is accessible from the class as a "metaclass field". So if one metaclass is used for multiple classes then fields on the metaclass are shared between those classes.

Note that `__init__` on metaclass is not the same as `__init__` on class. These are unrelated. Also `__call__` becomes a new "constructor". Check this out:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __call__(self):
...         return 1

>>> class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
...     pass

>>> Foo()
1
```

Comment: so   `__init__`  `__del__`  `__new__`  are define on default meta class `type` as its metaclass field. Am i right?

Comment: @RavinduShantha Yes.